# ValueError: could not convert string to float: yes while fitting a model using gridsearch from scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have this assignment where I use SVC() and best gridsearchCV() from scikit learn to fit a model. Bit I am getting can not convert string to float. All my X_train data seem to int64 and float64. But y_train data are "yes" and "no". I wonder some how I have to turn them into numbers before calling clf.fit(), not sure what function to run on y_train to turn the labels.

I get the error on the last line where I call the fit on grid_obj. I am not sure where the strings are that can not be converted!? Thanks.

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def performance_metric(y_true, y_predict):
    """ Calculates and returns the performance score between 
        true and predicted values based on the metric chosen. """  
    score = r2_score(y_true,y_predict)        
    # Return the score
    return score 


# TODO: Create the parameters list you wish to tune
parameters =  parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'gamma':[1,100,1000],'C':[1, 10,100]}


# TODO: Initialize the classifier
clf = clf_A

# TODO: Make an f1 scoring function using 'make_scorer' 
f1_scorer = make_scorer(performance_metric, greater_is_better=True)  # None

from sklearn import svm
regressor = svm.SVR() #SVM regression

# TODO: Perform grid search on the classifier using the f1_scorer as the scoring method
grid_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=parameters, scoring=f1_scorer) 

# TODO: Fit the grid search object to the training data and find the optimal parameters
datasets = [train_test_split(X_all, y_all, train_size=x, test_size=95) for x in [100, 200, 300]]
#print datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = datasets[2]
print X_train
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

X_all data:
Feature values:

```
  school sex  age address famsize Pstatus  Medu  Fedu     Mjob      Fjob  \
0     GP   F   18       U     GT3       A     4     4  at_home   teacher   
1     GP   F   17       U     GT3       T     1     1  at_home     other   
2     GP   F   15       U     LE3       T     1     1  at_home     other   
3     GP   F   15       U     GT3       T     4     2   health  services   
4     GP   F   16       U     GT3       T     3     3    other     other   

    ...    higher internet  romantic  famrel  freetime goout Dalc Walc health  \
0   ...       yes       no        no       4         3     4    1    1      3   
1   ...       yes      yes        no       5         3     3    1    1      3   
2   ...       yes      yes        no       4         3     2    2    3      3   
3   ...       yes      yes       yes       3         2     2    1    1      5   
4   ...       yes       no        no       4         3     2    1    2      5   

  absences  
0        6  
1        4  
2       10  
3        2  
4        4
```

X_train:

```
   school_GP  school_MS  sex_F  sex_M  age  address_R  address_U  \
130        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        1.0        0.0   
230        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
318        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        1.0        0.0   
365        0.0        1.0    0.0    1.0   18        1.0        0.0   
345        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
295        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   17        0.0        1.0
     famsize_GT3  famsize_LE3  Pstatus_A    ...     higher  internet  \
130          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
230          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
318          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
365          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
345          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1  
     romantic  famrel  freetime  goout  Dalc  Walc  health  absences  
130         1       4         2      2     2     2       5         0  
230         1       3         2      3     1     2       3        14  
318         0       4         3      4     2     5       5         0  
365         0       3         3      4     2     4       3         4  
345         1       5         4      3     2     3       1         7  
295         0       4         4      3     1     3       5         4
```

Comment: What's in `X_all` ?

Comment: X_all = student_data[feature_cols]
y_all = student_data[target_col]  X_all are the features for a student like address, sex, age,.... and y_all is the prediction

Comment: So you have indeed `str` values in your dataset. Any chance this is where the strings are then?

Comment: in X_all there are but all is converted to numbers in X-train as you can see school_GP  school_MS  sex_F  sex_M  age  address_R  address_U  \
130        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        1.0        0.0   
230        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0

Comment: Can you please add a small data sample in your post?

Comment: from X-all or X_train? I am not sure if I can edit my original post now.

Comment: of course you can :)

Comment: added X+All and X_train

Comment: Can you see anything off if you try `>> X_train.dtypes`?

Comment: All data types are int64 and float64

Comment: How about y_train data being"yes" and "no", should they not be changed to "1' and '0"?